# disabling alt-tab (possibly windows key as well) lua

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to comprehend a bit of Lua to write a simple WoW addon which would in simple terms disable only the alt+tab functionality of windows when you've entered the world.

More specifically, there are 3 modifier keys in WoW: shift, control and alt, and I find myself sometimes using the alt modifier to do an action however during that intentional spam I also try to do a target switch which is done using the tab key (the simple way would of course be to change the button for the target switch, however I do not have any other available options that would end as a performance improvement).

The idea is that from the WoW API I get an event that fires when the player enters the world (that's not somebody should actually care about however to put it simply it's an event called PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD which triggers every time you zone in with a loading screen if somebody here has played WoW). My main problem is: is there an actual way using Lua code to disable the alt-tab key combination while keeping the functionality of alt as a modifier key in WoW and tab as a regular "taret switch" key in WoW?

If more info is needed I'd try to provide it, however I'm hoping it's as simple as "Event happens (you entered the world)... well let's execute the code  end of story".

Thanks for any possible answers, looking forward to them.

Comment: There is no way from inside WoW Lua. Also, the obvious place to ask for this would be the WoW forums, here is a solution using AutoHotkey: http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/2592858902#18

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, windows makes it intentionally [hard to disable](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;125614) (basically, you have to  RegisterHotKey()). Since I don't think the Lua API of World of Warcraft allows you to programmatically rebind hotkeys due to its built-in restrictions, what you are asking for might not be possible in that particular Lua environment.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot kazagistar, I guess that's an option out of the window, been researching for a while but I didn't find anything and your info just solidifies my "I guess I should quit trying" option.

Even if it was possible I'd follow Nathanyel's suggestion to ask the devs for an implementation even though one would think that they should have figured it out by now :))

Comment: Hotkeys are usually stored as part of your account, and are stored online. Allowing an addon to mess with them would allow you significantly mess up the user's game beyond just the addon, and possibly automate way more then would be "fair". Hence the restrictions.